# How can I use GameplayKit State Machine for sprite animation?

Tags: sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I have two animations for my player to run and jump. Can I control these animations using GameplayKit's state machines? If so, how? In this project, I use SpriteKit and GameplayKit for Entity-Component architecture and State Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set first the StateMachine and fill with your custom classes

```
self.playerStateMachine = GKStateMachine(states: [
    PlayerRunning(player),
    PlayerJumping(player)
])
```

Then when you need to enter to state, can be with:

```
self.playerStateMachine?.enter(PlayerRunning.self)
```

On the state you can perform changes like:

```
override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
    self.player?.run(runAnimation)
}
```

Example:

[image]

Please take a look of complete example here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/StateMachineAnimation/StateMachineAnimation/GameScene.swift

Comment: Thank you, Maetschl.